# Como nomear as pastas na estrutura MVC do PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Como deve ser a nomeação das pastas no MVC? Em letras maiúsculas ou minusculas? E os arquivos? Como devem ser nomeados? Os controllers, devem ter 'Controller' no final ou apenas o nome? E a nomeação dos models? Devem ser no singular e contendo 'Model' no final do nome do arquivo ou apenas o nome dele?

Achei algumas informações no PHP-FIG quanto a nomeação de arquivos, mas não na estrutura MVC

Comment: Não existe regra que dita isso, você pode implementar da forma que melhor se adequar às suas necessidades. MVC é um conceito (uma ideia/filosofia), não é concreto, então ele não dita nada sobre como será a implementação.

Comment: Eu sempre utilizo o padrão do Laravel por me sentir mais confortável. Cada um usa o que achar melhor.

Answer (score 3):

MVC (Model-View-Controller) é um padrão de arquitetura de software onde não torna-se obrigatório determinar diretamente o nome de diretórios e arquivos, porém, você pode seguir o conceito utilizado por alguns Frameworks de sucesso que seguem esse padrão, por exemplo, a estrutura de diretórios do Laravel 4.2 esta toda em letras minúsculas e no plural:

**controllers**, **models**, **views**

As classes criadas em **controllers** seguem o seguinte padrão: **NomeDaClasseController.php**;
Já as classes criadas em **models** seguem o padrão: **Nome.php**;
E as classes criadas em **views** seguem o padrão: **nome.php** ou **nome.blade.php** (no caso de utilizar o Blade para templates).

Answer (score 0):

Não tem uma regra definida, mas o padrão utilizado pela maioria é:

Models: aonde se encontra as variáveis e métodos de manipulação de dados, ex, uma classe cliente que contém nome, CPF... como atributos, e métodos de manipulação na base de dados, uma vez que você também possa extrair estes métodos de manipulação para uma terceira classe, deixando apenas atributos e outros tipos de métodos na model.

Controllers: manipula as telas, exibe mensagens, redireciona para outras páginas... basicamente é isso.

Views: são suas páginas Html.